# Error of approximating a Gaussian integral by a series

Tags: calculus

I want to bound the following error
$$|\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\sigma}e^{-\frac{n^2}{2\sigma^2}}- \int^{\infty}_0 \frac{1}{\sigma}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}} \,dt| $$

By Taylor's theorem one can see that for a general $C^2$ function $f$,
$$|b_n|=|f(n)-\int^{n+1/2}_{n-1/2} f(s) \,ds|\leq \frac{1}{24}\sup\{|f^{\prime\prime}(t)|:|n-t|\leq \frac{1}{2}\}$$

Using this, I computed that $|b_n| \leq C\frac{1}{\sigma^5}e^{-\frac{(n-0.5)^2}{2\sigma^2}}(n^2-\sigma^2)$, where $C$ is some constant.

Now taking the sum of $b_n$, I got the error is bounded by $C^\prime \frac{1}{\sigma^2}$.

I wonder if this bound is correct?

Comment: 1) Do you know that $\int^{\infty}_0 \frac{1}{\sigma}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}}dt$ is equal to $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ (in particular **independant from $\sigma$**) ? 2) It is difficult to say that it is an "approximation"... a "gap" would be more exact.

Comment: the integral evaluates to $\sqrt{\pi/2}$ independent from $\sigma$ indeed. However this doesn’t mean the error is independent form $\sigma$. When the variance is small, the Gaussian density has larger derivative around zero, which means we will have larger error when we approximate with step size 1. So I don’t see what you are trying to say here? Can you please clarify?